# Why I don't have Undo History in Sculpt Mode?

Tags: interface, workflow, sculpting

When working in Sculpt Mode, I don't have an *Undo History* of my brush strokes when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>. Is this a regular behaviour or a known limitation?

Comment: maybe, but you can still undo/redo, at some level (ctrl-Z, shift-ctrl-Z)

Comment: Of course, but if you're working with high dense meshes, every step takes 5-10 seconds.

Comment: Yes, sadly. Tell that to me, when I was learning 1.6x (not a typo, really 1.6x) without any undo everywhere :D